# Is there a file manager that allows grouping of bookmarks in a side panel?

Tags: nautilus, files, dolphin, nemo

I would like to have a file manager that I can group folder locations under customised group names in a sidebar.  I have played around with Ubuntu Nautilus, Nemo and Dolphin and can't seem to achieve this.

Currently in Nemo my side bar shows:

> > My Computer
>
> > Devices
>
> > Network

I can drag folders into these, but I would like to add my own group headings, e.g.:

> > My Computer
>
> > Devices
>
> > Network
>
> > Website Files
>
> > Project files

Does anyone know a file manager that can do this or a plug in for one? Or the setting I am missing? Thanks